# Best Practice: Should one avoid bi-directional relationships?

Tags: language-agnostic, datamodel

I wonder what the best practice is to deal with a data model like this:
[image: Simple security model]

We have 3 entities:

- Role
- User
- Permission

Note that the entities are represented as java classes and will be mapped to a database via hibernate, anyway I think the question could be answered without having knowledge of these technologies.

There is a many-to-many relationship between `Role` & `User` and between `Role` & `Permission`.

**Is it ok to have a bi-directional relationship here?** So, that you can ask `Role` to give you all his members and to ask `User` to give you all his roles.

It's very comfortable that you can ask both entities, however one drawback is that whenever you remove a relationship you have to manage both entities.

E.g. if you remove `Role` from a `User` you have also to remove the `User` from the `Role`. This can be quite annoying if there are many of these relationships. Therefore I would like what the best practice is.

Comment: Can't see why it's being voted off topic. Data modelling isn't just about SQL databases, it's something programmers do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to avoid bidirectional relationships. Instead replace one direction with an explicit query in you DAO/Repository. Keeps the model simpler and if done correctly via interfaces the application clean of circular dependencies

Comment: One directional relationship are easier manage. You might have to go to a bi-directional relationship if the explicit query/look-up results in performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to have a bi-directional relationship here? So, that you can ask Role to give you all his members and to ask User to give you all his roles.

Yes. If you actually need the navigability in both ways, then there's no reason to prevent yourself from obtaining it in the simplest way possible.

> one drawback is that whenever you remove a relationship you have to manage both entities.

This depends on the implementation, one could implement the data model in a way that would synchronise both "ends".